# How to avoid simultaneous audio playing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Good morning to everyone,
I'm a web designer (with some jquery, html and css skills), not a developer, so i could write something wrong, but unfortunately in those days i have to face a lot of code.

I have an html page composed by  elements. 
Each one would have to play a different audio file with a click() function.
I assigned a different id to the divs elements and i had been able to make them play the audio file, but i can't avoid the simultaneous play of audio samples ( if the user clicks on another button the other audio files would have to stop).

This is the sample of the html in the page

```
<div id="audio1"></div>
<div id="audio2"></div>
<div id="audio3"></div>
```

this is the script to make the first div play an audio file

```
<script>     
     $(document).ready(function() {
        var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
            audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'assets/esternos2.mp3');
            //audioElement.load()

        $.get();

        audioElement.addEventListener("load", function() {
            audioElement.play();
        }, true);

        $('#audio1').click(function() {
            audioElement.play();
        });

    });
</script>
```

With that code the div plays the audio after a click. Now my first problem is to create a variable that assign a different audio file to the other divs. 
And then avoid the simultaneous play of the audio samples.
I would really appreciate any answer or help. Have a nice day.

Comment: Call `audioElement.stop()` before you change to the next audio clip. You can also remove the `$.get()` call too.

Comment: ok, thank you very much. And thanks for editing my code, i saw that it was a mess. Sorry, my first question here

Comment: how can i create a variable for the audio samples? with a switch?

Comment: You've not really shown what you're trying to do so I can't guide you. You already have the `audioElement` variable, is that not working? Is there a reason why the `click()` handlers don't work?

Comment: Sorry i'm working on localhost. I'll put a sample on the web. Really appreciate it

Comment: [link](http://codepen.io/beer_baron/pen/QjaZVr) I put it a sample on code pen